# HTACCESS Dealing with 2 RewriteRules

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^api/people/([^/]*)$ api/people.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^api/people/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ api/people.php?action=$1&id=$2
```

In the above example, there are to `RewriteRules` one detects if a url is for example `domain.com/api/people/1` and the other detects `domain.com/api/people/settings/1`

I usually get Error 500 when I try access the latter url, is there a way to sort out the HTACCESS so that it can detect if the url is either the first or last?

Comment: move the second rule above the first and stick an `[L]` flag at the end of the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^api/people/([^/]+)/?$ api/people.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^api/people/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ api/people.php?action=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```